# C# Initialize a login form BEFORE main form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community.
I developed an application and later I decide to insert a login form.
I developed the login form however I couldn´t make login form initialize BEFORE main form.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup the starting form of a winforms project in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981045/how-to-setup-the-starting-form-of-a-winforms-project-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: @LukeVo - I don't think that is a duplicate. The issue is making a login form start first and then be able to close it and only show the main form, and if you close the form that opens the app the whole app shuts down.

Comment: I've voted to re-open. I think the OP's issue is clear enough for anyone who has done winforms dev.

Comment: It has been solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973274/how-do-i-show-a-secondary-form-before-the-main-form

Comment: Add an event handler for MainForm Form Loading. In this event handler show your Login Dialog: `using (LoginDialog dlg = new LoginDialog()) {...}` Between the brackets you set the properties of your login dlg, and end with: `var dlgResult = dlg.ShowDialog(this);` This will show the login dialog before your main dialog shows. People have to finish the dialog, and you can return a DlgResult, which you can interpret in your main form event handler: `swhich (dlgResult)` if Ok, then read login data, if not, call `this.Close();` to close the application.

Comment: Use `Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new LoginForm());`

Comment: @I_Al-thamary I liked your link more. When LoginForm closes the main thread is killed. This method can work, with more care but a novice may have trouble with it

Comment: @I_Al-thamary - The link you've given does not show how to keep the main form alive after the login form closes.

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse - You should post your answer in the duplicate question. I don't think any of the answers in the duplicate are as good as yours. The duplicate seems quite terrible really.

Comment: Just show your login form within main() in program.cs via ShowDialog() and capture the result.  If good, continue on to the Application.Run() line with the main form within.  Otherwise just let the app quit when it hits the end of main()...

Comment: @Enigmativity he needs to show it after login or as he likes

Comment: @I_Al-thamary - If the form in the `Application.Run(new Form())` is closed the whole app shuts down. The issue here is to solve that.

Comment: @Enigmativity They can use in the LoginForm  `this.hide();
new MainForm().ShowDialog();`

Comment: These are different methods [How can I close a login form and show the main form without my application closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759334/how-can-i-close-a-login-form-and-show-the-main-form-without-my-application-closi/4759407)

Comment: @I_Al-thamary - That's a far better duplicate.